# Java Example With Cxf Web Services ~ Runtime Exception

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I'm trying to create client with apache-cxf.
I need to run following web service http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl
What i'm trying to achieve is i will give two parameters to this service and return result/response.

Here is my code below:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dfc = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dfc.createClient("http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl");

Object res[] = client.invoke("echo", "test echo");
System.out.println("Result: " + res[0]);
```

I'm getting lots of error such as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error compiling schema from WSDL at {http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl}: Unexpected <schema> appears at line 9 column 5
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory$InnerErrorListener.fatalError(DynamicClientFactory.java:759)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.fatalError(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.ErrorReceiverFilter.fatalError(ErrorReceiverFilter.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$2.fatalError(ParserContext.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.unexpectedX(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:506)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.unexpectedEnterElement(NGCCHandler.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.Schema.enterElement(Schema.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.startElement(NGCCRuntime.java:258)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.SubtreeCutter.startElement(SubtreeCutter.java:108)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.startElement(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:150)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.startElement(IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.java:128)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.CustomizationContextChecker.startElement(CustomizationContextChecker.java:193)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.startElement(DOMForestScanner.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestParser.parse(DOMForestParser.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:347)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:157)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:534)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:189)
    at TestCAse.main(TestCAse.java:8)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl; systemId: http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 5; Unexpected <schema> appears at line 9 column 5
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.unexpectedX(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:499)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because the WSDL that's published at that address is invalid. The specific point of failure that CXF is complaining about is this:

```
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SoapResponder.xsd"></schema>
</types>
```

Notice the unqualified use of the `<schema>` tag? That tag is provided within the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace, qualified with the prefix `xsd`. What should be in the WSDL is:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SoapResponder.xsd"></xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Why it turned out incorrectly is beyond me; afterall, the namespace and the prefix are properly declared at the top in the wsdl:

```
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema".
```

---

To resolve, save a local copy of that wsdl, make an edit to correct the unqualified tag use, and then use the corrected local copy in your application

Comment: Thank you for your answer but now im getting this error -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no source files